# Transformation of the independent variable of signals

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis

I am struggling to understand the concept of transformation of the independent variable of signals.

Let $x[n]$ be a DT time signal.

As per my understanding, $x$ is a function of $n$, so it is not possible to write lets say $x[n-n_o]$.

By applying the transformation $n=u-u_0$ and considering the composite function $y[u]=x[u-u_o]$, $y$ is not a function of $n$.

What is a correct mathematical way to express that $y[n]$ is $x[n]$ shifted by $n_o$ units to the right?

Answer (score 2):

The independent variable denotes here any of  the locations or indices at which $x$ is defined. The symbolic name or notation of the independent variable does not matter *per se*, as long as is a valid index, here for discrete time series an integer. It could be $n$, $k$, $u-u_0+u_{-1}$, $\pi /(1-1/3+1/5-1/7\ldots)$ (or $4$), as long as it is a valid integer.

What is important is that index notations are consistent when different entities are written together in equations: $y[n] = x[k]$ makes little sense, but $y[u] = x[u-u_0]$ perfectly does as long as $u$ and $u-u_0$ are integers. As long as  the indices at which $x$ is defined allow you to have a proper definition for $y$ in terms of indices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand the concept of representing integers with variables. I do not understand how after choosing a specific variable, say $n$, to represent the indexes of x, one can then write $x[n-n_o]$. $n-n_0$ might be an integer but its a different variable than $n$.

Comment: What if we call it independent index? Indeed, variable can be confusing

Comment: I think that doesn't work either because say $x[2n]$ is used to represent an entirely different signal, it is not only a matter of indexing.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. $2n$ are nice integer indices, they take $x$ on even locations

Answer (score 0):

> As per my understanding, $x$ is a function of $n$,

Correct

> so it is not possible to write lets say $x[n-n_o]$.

Why not ? The time variable can be transformed like any other variable so you can certainly write things like $x[n-k]$, $x[2n]$, $x[n^2]$, etc.

And yes, a time shift is simply

$$y[n] = x[n-n_0]$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is not possible to write $x[n-n_o]$ because $x$ is a function of $n$, not $n-n_o$.